# Banco de Dados SQLite não está inserindo valores

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Eu estou criando uma aplicação simples que envolve o banco de dados SQLite e ao longo do desenvolvimento minha função de inserir na tabela parou de funcionar. Através do debug pude notar que ela está executando até o final, porém os dados não estão sendo inseridos.

Tela de Cadastro

```
public class RestauranteCadastrar extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtNome, edtEndereco, edtDescricao;
    Button btnConfirmar;
    RestauranteDAO dao = new RestauranteDAO(RestauranteCadastrar.this);
    TextView txtListagem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurante_cadastrar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Mostrar o botão
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);      //Ativar o botão

        edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
        edtEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);
        edtDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescricao);
        btnConfirmar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);

        CarregarInicial();

        btnConfirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean camposPreenchidos = true;
                if (edtNome.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    edtNome.setError("Campo Obrigatório.");
                    edtNome.requestFocus();
                    camposPreenchidos = false;
                }

                if (edtEndereco.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    edtEndereco.setError("Campo Obrigatório.");
                    edtEndereco.requestFocus();
                    camposPreenchidos = false;
                }

                if (edtDescricao.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    edtDescricao.setError("Campo Obrigatório.");
                    edtDescricao.requestFocus();
                    camposPreenchidos = false;
                }

                if (camposPreenchidos){
                    Restaurante restaurante = new Restaurante();
                    restaurante.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());
                    restaurante.setDescricao(edtDescricao.getText().toString());
                    restaurante.setEndereco(edtEndereco.getText().toString());
                    restaurante.setLike(0);
                    restaurante.setDeslike(0);
                    restaurante.setLikeQuant(0);
                    restaurante.setDeslikeQuant(0);
                    dao.Abrir();
                    dao.Inserir(restaurante);
                    dao.Fechar();
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(RestauranteCadastrar.this, "Recomendação cadastrada com sucesso!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                    //finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void CarregarInicial(){
        RestauranteDAO dao = new RestauranteDAO(RestauranteCadastrar.this);

        dao.Abrir();

        Listar(dao);
    }

    public void Listar(RestauranteDAO dao){
        List<Restaurante> lista = dao.ListarTodos();

        txtListagem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtListagem);
        txtListagem.setText("");

        for (Restaurante c: lista){  //for each
            txtListagem.setText(txtListagem.getText().toString() + c.getId() + "-" +c.getNome() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Classe DAO onde se encontra a função inserir;

```
public class RestauranteDAO {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper helper;

    public RestauranteDAO(Context context){
        helper = new DBHelper(context);
    }
    public void Abrir(){
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    public void Fechar(){
        helper.close();
    }

    public long Inserir(Restaurante restaurante){
        ContentValues dados = new ContentValues();
        String query = "select * from restaurante";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        dados.put("ID", count);
        dados.put("Nome", restaurante.getNome());
        dados.put("Descricao", restaurante.getDescricao());
        dados.put("Endereco", restaurante.getEndereco());
        dados.put("Like", restaurante.getLike());
        dados.put("Deslike", restaurante.getDeslike());
        dados.put("LiqueQuant", restaurante.getLikeQuant());
        dados.put("DeslikeQuant", restaurante.getDeslikeQuant());

        long rowid = db.insert(DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE, null, dados);
        return rowid;
    }

    public long Atualizar(int id, int like, int deslike){
        ContentValues dados = new ContentValues();
        String where = "ID = " + id;

        Abrir();
        dados.put("Like", like);
        dados.put("Deslike", deslike);

        long rowid = db.update(DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE, dados, where, null);
        Fechar();
        return rowid;
    }

    public Cursor carregaDados(){
        Cursor cursor;
        Abrir();
        cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE, new String[]{"ID", "Nome", "Descricao", "Endereco", "Like", "Deslike", "LikeQuant", "DeslikeQuant"}, null, null, null, null, "ID", null);
        if(cursor!=null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        Fechar();
        return cursor;
    }

    public ArrayList procurarID(int id){
        db = this.helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select * from " + DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        int idComparacao = 99;
        String vNome = "HQPZM", vDescricao = "HQPZM";
        int vLike = 0, vDeslike = 0;
        String vEndereco = "HQPZM";
        int vLikeQuant = 0, vDeslikeQuant = 0;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                idComparacao = cursor.getInt(0);
                if (idComparacao == id){
                    vNome = cursor.getString(1);
                    vDescricao = cursor.getString(2);
                    vLike = cursor.getInt(3);
                    vDeslike = cursor.getInt(4);
                    vEndereco = cursor.getString(5);
                    vLikeQuant = cursor.getInt(6);
                    vDeslikeQuant = cursor.getInt(7);
                    break;
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        ArrayList vetResult = new ArrayList();
        vetResult.add(idComparacao); //0
        vetResult.add(vNome);        //1
        vetResult.add(vDescricao);   //2
        vetResult.add(vLike);        //3
        vetResult.add(vDeslike);     //4
        vetResult.add(vEndereco);    //5
        vetResult.add(vLikeQuant);   //6
        vetResult.add(vDeslikeQuant);//7

        return(vetResult);
    }

    public List<Restaurante> ListarTodos(){
        List<Restaurante> lista = new ArrayList<Restaurante>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE, new String[]{"ID", "Nome", "Endereco", "Descricao"}, null, null, null, null, "Nome");

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Restaurante restaurante = new Restaurante();
            restaurante.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            restaurante.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
            restaurante.setDescricao(cursor.getString(2));

            lista.add(restaurante);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Não consigo identificar o que possa estar errado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você substituir `long rowid = db.insert(DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE, null, dados);` por `long rowid = db.insertOrThrow(DBHelper.TBL_RESTAURANTE, null, dados);`, ele funcionará, se der algo errado ele vai te retornar o erro. Bjos